# JAVA pdfbox PDF to very simple HTML

Tags: java, html, pdf, pdfbox

I would like to build an application which converts PDF Screenplays in HTML. Screenplays are very simple texts with no image nor other kind of objects, but formatting is very important.
Fortunately there aren't much formatting conventions either.

That said, I found in the internet the PDFbox java library and I would like to use it, but I can't find examples on how retreiving information about formatting (or about coordinates of the text).

What I need is to know the margin box coordinates and the ones of the text so I can compare them to check whether the text is indented or not.

I hope I've been clear enough.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/commandline.html#extracttext

"-html  boolean false   Output in HTML format instead of raw text."

This looks like what you need.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but no, it does not do what I'd like. 
I need to know text coordinates please

Comment: Is your actual requirement converting PDF's as it is to HTML or extracting text from PDF, indent and create HTML. Are you open to programs other than PDFBox?

Comment: Good catch, @Emily, I wonder why there is no such an example as extract html from pdf on the pdfbox official site, it could be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this [link](https://jackson-brain.com/using-pdfbox-to-locate-text-coordinates-within-a-pdf-in-java/). I think it will help you. Anyway I am copying the code from there in case if the link is broken...

```
package printtextlocations;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.pdfbox.exceptions.InvalidPasswordException;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
 import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.common.PDStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripper;
import org.apache.pdfbox.util.TextPosition;

public class PrintTextLocations extends PDFTextStripper {

public static StringBuilder tWord = new StringBuilder();
public static String seek;
public static String[] seekA;
public static List wordList = new ArrayList();
public static boolean is1stChar = true;
public static boolean lineMatch;
public static int pageNo = 1;
public static double lastYVal;

public PrintTextLocations()
        throws IOException {
    super.setSortByPosition(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
        throws Exception {
    PDDocument document = null;
    seekA = args[1].split(",");
    seek = args[1];
    try {
        File input = new File(args[0]);
        document = PDDocument.load(input);
        if (document.isEncrypted()) {
            try {
                document.decrypt("");
            } catch (InvalidPasswordException e) {
                System.err.println("Error: Document is encrypted with a password.");
                System.exit(1);
            }
        }
        PrintTextLocations printer = new PrintTextLocations();
        List allPages = document.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();

        for (int i = 0; i < allPages.size(); i++) {
            PDPage page = (PDPage) allPages.get(i);
            PDStream contents = page.getContents();

            if (contents != null) {
                printer.processStream(page, page.findResources(), page.getContents().getStream());
            }
            pageNo += 1;
        }
    } finally {
        if (document != null) {
            System.out.println(wordList);
            document.close();
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void processTextPosition(TextPosition text) {
    String tChar = text.getCharacter();
    System.out.println("String[" + text.getXDirAdj() + ","
            + text.getYDirAdj() + " fs=" + text.getFontSize() + " xscale="
            + text.getXScale() + " height=" + text.getHeightDir() + " space="
            + text.getWidthOfSpace() + " width="
            + text.getWidthDirAdj() + "]" + text.getCharacter());
    String REGEX = "[,.\\[\\](:;!?)/]";
    char c = tChar.charAt(0);
    lineMatch = matchCharLine(text);
    if ((!tChar.matches(REGEX)) && (!Character.isWhitespace(c))) {
        if ((!is1stChar) && (lineMatch == true)) {
            appendChar(tChar);
        } else if (is1stChar == true) {
            setWordCoord(text, tChar);
        }
    } else {
        endWord();
    }
}

protected void appendChar(String tChar) {
    tWord.append(tChar);
    is1stChar = false;
}

protected void setWordCoord(TextPosition text, String tChar) {
    tWord.append("(").append(pageNo).append(")[").append(roundVal(Float.valueOf(text.getXDirAdj()))).append(" : ").append(roundVal(Float.valueOf(text.getYDirAdj()))).append("] ").append(tChar);
    is1stChar = false;
}

protected void endWord() {
    String newWord = tWord.toString().replaceAll("[^\\x00-\\x7F]", "");
    String sWord = newWord.substring(newWord.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1);
    if (!"".equals(sWord)) {
        if (Arrays.asList(seekA).contains(sWord)) {
            wordList.add(newWord);
        } else if ("SHOWMETHEMONEY".equals(seek)) {
            wordList.add(newWord);
        }
    }
    tWord.delete(0, tWord.length());
    is1stChar = true;
}

protected boolean matchCharLine(TextPosition text) {
    Double yVal = roundVal(Float.valueOf(text.getYDirAdj()));
    if (yVal.doubleValue() == lastYVal) {
        return true;
    }
    lastYVal = yVal.doubleValue();
    endWord();
    return false;
}

protected Double roundVal(Float yVal) {
    DecimalFormat rounded = new DecimalFormat("0.0'0'");
    Double yValDub = new Double(rounded.format(yVal));
    return yValDub;
}
}
```